# Showing existing comments and textbox for new comment in WindowsPhone app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am writing my first app for Windows Phone 7.5. A simplified version of one of the scenarios I am trying to implement is:

**Scenario:** I am trying to add functionality for user to be able to write a 'comment' on a certain 'thread'/'post'/'title' while showing him the comments already posted by others. Something similar to How Facebook posts are shown in WP.

**Tried:** I tried ListBox and ItemsControl.  But none of those are easy to use for this scenario. Is there any in-built control in WP SDK, which can help me in implementing the above mentioned scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some third part control. [This one](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/07/a-wp7-conversation-view/) for example.